# Time Machine analog for Linux

Tags: background-process

On my Apple Mac I use TimeMachine to save backups.

This is effortless and quite reliable and provides access to time-stamped historical files going back years. It is also efficient (the backups basically create full images, hardlinking to unchanged content to minimise storage requirements).

My question is there an equivalent for Linux based OS. This would seem to be feasible on Linux, but I am not aware of a similar tool.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_backup_software  . Back in TIme has a similar naming and description.

Comment: Time Machine on macOS does a full system backup. Do you require this on Linux as well, or are you only interested in backing up e.g. your home directory?

Comment: rsnapshot is a wonderful tool for this, however this kind of question belongs on software recs.

Comment: LVM has an option for that.